# Injection of ViewModels without a Service Locator

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I personally think that Service Locator is an anti-pattern, but I find it really common to see a "ViewModelLocator" from which each view takes its DataSource in XAML-based applications.

How is this avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MVVM framework that uses conventions, like Caliburn.Micro. In Caliburn, you register you ViewModel to a DI container when the app starts.
Then when you have a TestView it is automatically bound to a TestViewModel (convention by name, the framework looks up the ViewModel in the DI container, gets/creates an instance and binds it.).